# Add item to the list in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here i am trying to add an item to the list using concat method

```
class AddItem extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
    myList:this.props.myList,
    value:''
    }
  }

  onChangeValue=(e)=>{
    this.setState({
      value:e.target.value
    })
  }
  add=()=>{
    this.setState({
      myList:this.state.myList.concat(value)
    });
    return{
      list,value:''
    };
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
       <ul>
        {this.state.myList.map((item)=>
         <li key={item}>{item}</li>
        )}
       </ul>
       <input type='text' onChange={this.onChangeValue}/>
      <button onClick={this.add}>Add Item</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

It throws below error
'myList is not defined'
'value is not defined'I
What is the issue here?

Answer (score 2):

```
this.state = {
  myList: this.props.myList || [],
  value: ""
};
```

or

```
  <ul>
    {(this.state.myList || []).map((item)=>
     <li key={item}>{item}</li>
   )}
```

you should set a default value for your state myList when props is undefined

Comment: tried it and its not working. Also got an  script error while click on the add item button

Comment: return{
      list,value:''
    };
have you defined your `list` and `value`

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-class-components-h2hl9?file=/src/index.js:442-501
hope this help. i have commented your issue line code

Answer (score 0):

Also, do bind functions onChangeValue and add inside constructor like this;

```
this.add=this.add.bind(this)
this.onChangeValue=this.onChangeValue.bind(this).
```

Add the above two lines in your constructor.

Comment: That's not required. Experimental syntax has already been introduced.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try this:

```
 add=()=>{
    this.setState({
      myList:this.state.myList.concat(value)
    });
    return{
      this.state.myList,
      this.state.value: ''
    };
}
```